# SLSQP doesn't respect constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have this nonlinear optimization problem

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
 
# Constants
mud = 0.6
fyd_mm2 = 1.1
fxd_mm2 = 3.5
 
# Inputs
Nxd_norm = 0.5
ratio_lwhw = 2
tw = 0.15
hw = 3
 
# derived constants
fyd = fyd_mm2*1e6
fxd = fxd_mm2*1e6
 
# derived inputs
lw = hw * ratio_lwhw
Nxd = Nxd_norm * lw * tw * fxd
 
def ey2v(x):
    return (lw-x[0])/2
 
def ey2m(x):
    return (lw-x[1])/2
 
def alpha(x):
    return x[2]
 
def Nxdv(x):
    delta = 0
    if ey2v(x) == ey2m(x):
        delta = 0.0000001
    return Nxd*ey2m(x)/(hw*math.tan(alpha(x))-ey2v(x)+ey2m(x)+delta)
 
def Nxdm(x):
    return Nxd-Nxdv(x)
 
def VRd(x):
   return Nxdv(x)*math.tan(alpha(x))
 
# x = l2v, l2m, alpha
def F(x):
    alpha = x[2]
    ey2m = (lw-x[1])/2
    ey2v = (lw-x[0])/2
    # avoid possible null division
    delta = 0
    if ey2v == ey2m:
        delta = 0.0000001
    Nxdv = Nxd*ey2m/(hw*math.tan(alpha)-ey2v+ey2m+delta)
    VRd = Nxdv*math.tan(alpha)
    r = VRd/lw/fyd/tw
    return -r
   
x0 = (4.1, 5.1, 0.54)
 
con1 = lambda x: Nxdv(x)/x[0]/math.cos(alpha(x))/math.cos(alpha(x))
con2 = lambda x: Nxdm(x)/x[1]
con3 = lambda x: math.tan(x[2])
con4 = lambda x: x[0]+math.tan(x[2])*hw

cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con1, 'ub': fyd*tw, 'lb': 0 },
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con2, 'ub': (fxd-fyd)*tw, 'lb': 0 },
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con3, 'ub': mud, 'lb': -100000 },
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con4, 'ub': lw, 'lb': -10000 }]

res = minimize(F, [lw/2, lw/4, 0.4], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
print(res)
print('con1: ', con1(res.x), ', con2: ', con2(res.x), ', con3: ', con3(res.x), ', con4: ', con4(res.x))
print('con1: ', fyd*tw, ', con2: ', (fxd-fyd)*tw, ', con3: ', mud, ', con4: ', lw)
```

The problem is, this codes yields this:

```
    fun: -1.5909091565619955
     jac: array([ 1.56119466e-04,  0.00000000e+00, -3.17994511e+00])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 543
     nit: 87
    njev: 85
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 7.23940719e-09, -1.01853916e+04,  7.06858349e+00])
con1:  435118518573387.75 , con2:  -3.869023343449402e-09 , con3:  1.0000000412925607 , con4:  3.0000001311170896
con1:  165000.0 , con2:  360000.0 , con3:  0.6 , con4:  6
```

so it says successfully, however the conditions (last 2 lines) are clearly not met. Why? By the way, x0 was chosen to be very close the the true optimium (this problem can be solved analytically for this set of input values, for other values there is no analytical solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for lower and upper bounds in dictionary constraints. You need reformulate the constraints functions to respect the bounds. Note that `lb <= fun(x) <= ub` is equivalent to the constraints `fun(x) - lb >= 0` and `ub - fun(x) >= 0`. Alternatively, you can use [`NonlinearConstraint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint) objects:

```py
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint

cons = [
    NonlinearConstraint(con1, 0, fyd*tw),
    NonlinearConstraint(con2, 0, (fxd-fyd)*tw),
    NonlinearConstraint(con3, -100000, mud),
    NonlinearConstraint(con4, -10000, lw)
]
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, I thought I had red the docs carefully. Thank you